# How to find the nth term of a Taylor series in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

Is there a way to compute the nth term of a Taylor series expansion without defining the value of n? In the case of sine it is `(-1)**n*x**(2*n+1)/(2*n+1)!`. In Maxima it is a (somewhat) related form to do it with `powerseries(sin(x), x, 0)`.

Comment: Not yet, although I believe this Google Summer of Code project will provide a way https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/GSoC-2014-Application-Avichal-Dayal-Series-Expansion

Comment: Oh, great. Can you add that as an answer? I mean, it is not possible right now with the built-in capabilities and that answer the question (so far).

Answer (score 0):

Use the mathematical expression: f^(n)(x) / n! x^n:

```
diff(f(x), *[x for _ in xrange(n)]) / factorial(n) * x**n
```

The `*` magic is just unpacking the list:

```
 diff(f(x), *[x, x, x])
```

is equivalent to:

```
 diff(f(x), x, x, x)
```

Comment: Davidmh this will not work, `n` is an integer symbol, so Python cannot create a list with `n` has one of the limits.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sequence of numbers:

4, 10, 16, 22, 28

The nth term of a sequence is always written in the form "?n + ?".

The number in front of the "n" is always the difference to get from one term to the next. Since the difference is 6, the first part of our rule will be "6n". The rule follows the six times table: 6, 12, 18, 24... etc.

The numbers in the sequence are always 2 less than the 6 times table so we "adjust" our rule by subtracting 2. Now putting this together gives us: 
nth term = 6n - 2.

Your Welcome happy to help:-)